# Hiding the application main icon in iPhone once the app installed

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, hide

I am working on one application in which I need to install the application on iPhone in such a way that it's icon is not being displayed in iPhone after the application gets installed.

Is this feature available in iOS? Does apple support this kind of feature?

Comment: No, with normal phone and documented API, its not possible.. Its possible with Jailbroken iPhone.

Comment: it can be easily done: please follow the link http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/hide-applications.76176/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can't remove your App icon from the home screen completely, you can make it invisible. However, the icon, while invisible, can still be tapped. **Also, your App would never be approved for the App Store that way.**

How to make your App invisible:

1. Create a completely transparent PNG file, and use it as Icon. Enable the "Prerendered" checkbox to make sure no gradient is applied to your icon.
2. In your .plist file, remove the string "${PRODUCT_NAME}" from "Bundle display name"

Answer (score 1):

add this to the Info.plist of an app.

```
<key>SBAppTags</key>
  <array>
    <string>hidden</string>
  </array>
```

thats it.

Comment: Can you tell me how to achieve same for MacBook app?